# Terraform: each.value is null

Tags: terraform, nested-loops

I am getting error for my terraform configuration.
**"each.value is null. This value is null, so it does not have any attributes."**

My terraform configuration is

```
locals {
  transformed_connections = { for key, value in var.virtual_network_gateway_connections : key => value }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "example" {
  name            = var.name

resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway_connection" "example" {
  for_each = local.transformed_connections

  name            = each.value.name
  connection_type = each.value.connection_type
}


module "vnetgateway" {
  source                = location_to_the_path
  for_each              = var.virtual_network_gateway
  name                  = each.value.name
  virtual_network_gateway_connections   = each.value.virtual_network_gateway_connections
}
```

tfvars file is below

```
virtual_network_gateway = {
  "1st_gateway" = {
    name                        = "1st_gateway"
    virtual_network_gateway_connections = {
    "1st_connection" = {
        name        = "1st_connection"
        connection_type = "whatever"
    },
    "2nd_connection" = {
        name        = "2nd_connection"
        connection_type = "whatever"
    }
   },
   "2nd_gateway" = {
    name                        = "2nd_gateway"
    virtual_network_gateway_connections = {
    "1st_connection" = {
        name        = "1st_connection"
        connection_type = "whatever"
    },
    "2nd_connection" = {
        name        = "2nd_connection"
        connection_type = "whatever"
    }
   }
}
```

This is the full error

```
> Error: Attempt to get attribute from null value
>     │ 
>     │   on main.tf line 11, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway_connection" "example":
>     │   11:     name            = each.value.name
>     │     ├────────────────
>     │     │ each.value is null
>     │ 
>     │ This value is null, so it does not have any attributes.
>     
>     Error: Attempt to get attribute from null value
>     │ 
>     │   on main.tf line 12, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway_connection" "example":
>     │   12:     connection_type = each.value.connection_type
>     │     ├────────────────
>     │     │ each.value is null
>     │ 
>     │ This value is null, so it does not have any attributes.
```

So I am unable to iterate over the contents of local.transformed_connections. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the FULL error message, showing exact lines where the error occurs?

Comment: I have updated the question with full error.

Answer (score 0):

Your `virtual_network_gateway` is incorrect. It has parenthesis in the incorrect places. It should be:

```
virtual_network_gateway = {
  "1st_gateway" = {
    name                        = "1st_gateway"
    virtual_network_gateway_connections = {
    "1st_connection" = {
        name        = "1st_connection"
        connection_type = "whatever"
    },
    "2nd_connection" = {
        name        = "2nd_connection"
        connection_type = "whatever"
    }
   }},
   "2nd_gateway" = {
    name                        = "2nd_gateway"
    virtual_network_gateway_connections = {
    "1st_connection" = {
        name        = "1st_connection"
        connection_type = "whatever"
    },
    "2nd_connection" = {
        name        = "2nd_connection"
        connection_type = "whatever"
    }
   }
}
}
```

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. Yes, I just wanted to trim down the map here for clarity and mistakenly removed extra parenthesis, but the parenthesis in my configuration are correct. So that is not the cause of the error.